# Display property overridden by User Agent Stylesheet on Chrome version 25.0.1364.152

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have defined the folowing css property
`div { display: block; }`
On opera/firefox/safari property is ok. On my windows seven chrome version 25.0.1364.152 m user agent stylesheet overwrite it with `display: block` (still ok even if it's not mine) but on vista chrome version 25.0.1364.152 and mac chrome version 25.0.1364.152, user agent stylesheet overwrite with `display:none`

Comment: *if* the stylesheet default is display:none that seems like a major bug.

Comment: Renaming the class `ad-image` in `adimage` seems to fix this issue. It's the div class causing this issue. Perhaps ad-image is a chrome new browser class name.

Comment: Please post a document that demonstrates this and specify exactly which element is involved. This sounds like a misunderstanding, or possibly a browser add-on interfering.

Comment: I've simply used this [AD-gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/). The full sized image is not displayed in the case i specified. This only appear on chrome version 25.0.1364.152 (work perfectly on other browser). Renaming the class solved the problem on chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you have the Chrome addon "**AdBlock**" installed and active. 
You can access it in the top right corner of your browser and there temporary inactivate it to see the difference.

[image]

As you mentioned try removing "ad" from the class name to avoid AdBlock from hiding the element.

Comment: +1 for : try removing "ad" from the class name to avoid ad-blocker

Comment: Yes that's it. It's come from AdBlock. But this does not appear in the previous version of chrome, and on windows seven. Very strange thing.